# Javascript Jquery MovingBoxes Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the movingboxes plugin - https://github.com/chriscoyier/MovingBoxes
What I can't seem to do is something very basic; cycle the li elements round so that there is never a blank space before the first and after the last, if that makes sense.

I want to do this as the startPanel setting doesn't seem to work, so I can't set it to a middle li to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option for that slider, `wrap: true` ... this will make a clone of the first element, and a clone of the last element, and when you reach the end it will give you the impression of infinite scrolling.

```
jQuery('.your-element').movingBoxes({

    startPanel: 1,
    reducedSize: 0.9,
    fixedHeight: false,
    speed: 250,
    hashTags: false,
    //HEY HEYYY
    wrap: true,
    //HEY HEYYY
    buildNav: true,
    navFormatter: function(index, panel) {
      return "&#9679;"
    },
    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
    currentPanel: 'current',
    tooltipClass: 'tooltip',
    preinit: function(e, mb, tar) {},
    initialized: function(e, slider, tar) {  },
    initChange: function(e, slider, tar) {  },
    beforeAnimation: function(e, slider, tar) {},
    completed: function(e, slider, tar) { }
  });
```